# Android web services xml parsing

Tags: android, parsing, listview, soap

I am creating two java files one is Main.java and Category.java

I am adding Library file ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

But here output is not displaying.

I am doing soap XMl parsing.

Here Text view but I want to a List. Please Help me

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

private static String URL = "http://sygnetinfosol.com/webservice.asmx";



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
//        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        

    SoapObject request = GetSoapObject(METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = GetEnvelope(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Category",new Category().getClass());

    try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    Category[] Allrooms = RetrieveFromSoap(response);

    TextView actv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
    actv.setHint(Allrooms[0].Text1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static SoapObject GetSoapObject(String MethodName)
    {
    return new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,MethodName);
    }
    public static SoapSerializationEnvelope GetEnvelope(SoapObject Soap)
    {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Soap);
    return envelope;
    }

    public static Category[] RetrieveFromSoap(SoapObject soap)
    {
        Category[] categories = new Category[soap.getPropertyCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)soap.getProperty(i);
    Category category = new Category();
    Category.Text1 = pii.getProperty(0).toString();
    Category.Text2= pii.getProperty(1).toString();
    Category.Text3= pii.getProperty(2).toString();
    categories[i] = category;
    }
    return categories;
    }
  }
```

Category.java

```
public class Category implements KvmSerializable{    

public static String Text1;
public static String Text2;
public static String Text3;

public Category(){}


public Category(String lat, String longi, String address) {

    Text1 = lat;
    Text2 = longi;
    Text3 = address;
}


public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

    switch(arg0)
    {
    case 0:
        return Text1;
    case 1:
        return Text2;
    case 2:
        return Text3;
    }

    return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 3;
}

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Text1";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Text2";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Text3";
        break;
    default:break;
    }
}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        Text1 = value.toString();
        break;
    case 1:
        Text2 = value.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        Text3 = value.toString();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

LogCat

```
03-14 11:59:05.417: W/PackageManager(59): Code path for pkg : com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather changing from /data/app/com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-2.apk to /data/app/com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-1.apk
03-14 11:59:05.417: W/PackageManager(59): Resource path for pkg : com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather changing from /data/app/com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-2.apk to /data/app/com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-1.apk
03-14 11:59:05.422: D/PackageManager(59):   Activities: com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather.Main
03-14 11:59:05.462: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather uid=10039
03-14 11:59:06.276: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-  cache/data@app@com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-1.apk@classes.dex
03-14 11:59:06.282: D/PackageManager(59): New package installed in /data/app/com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-1.apk
03-14 11:59:07.162: D/dalvikvm(257): GC_EXPLICIT freed 154 objects / 11496 bytes in 87ms
03-14 11:59:07.192: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather uid=10039
03-14 11:59:07.282: D/dalvikvm(119): GC_EXPLICIT freed 791 objects / 44936 bytes in 85ms
03-14 11:59:07.392: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9323 objects / 576216 bytes in 149ms
03-14 11:59:07.662: W/RecognitionManagerService(59): no available voice recognition services found
03-14 11:59:07.872: D/dalvikvm(157): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1881 objects / 96152 bytes in 421ms
03-14 11:59:07.982: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4037 objects / 225296 bytes in 105ms
03-14 11:59:08.042: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather-2.apk@classes.dex
03-14 11:59:08.102: D/AndroidRuntime(575): Shutting down VM
03-14 11:59:08.112: D/dalvikvm(575): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-14 11:59:08.702: D/AndroidRuntime(588): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-14 11:59:08.702: D/AndroidRuntime(588): CheckJNI is ON
03-14 11:59:08.852: D/AndroidRuntime(588): --- registering native functions ---
03-14 11:59:09.572: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather/.Main }
03-14 11:59:09.912: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather for activity com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather/.Main: pid=594 uid=10039 gids={3003}
03-14 11:59:09.922: D/AndroidRuntime(588): Shutting down VM
03-14 11:59:09.922: D/jdwp(588): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-14 11:59:09.922: D/dalvikvm(588): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-14 11:59:09.952: I/dalvikvm(588): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
03-14 11:59:09.952: I/AndroidRuntime(588): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-14 11:59:11.171: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather/.Main: 1269 ms (total 1269 ms)
03-14 11:59:16.412: D/dalvikvm(119): GC_EXPLICIT freed 728 objects / 42320 bytes in 158ms
03-14 11:59:21.422: D/dalvikvm(265): GC_EXPLICIT freed 109 objects / 5360 bytes in 150ms
```

Comment: Have you added the permission to `INTERNET ACCESS` in your manifest file.

Comment: can you provide us log cat information.

Comment: Are you getting data i.e from your category object is it `null`

Comment: @Veerababu Medisetti I posted LogCat also you will see once please help me

Comment: androidHttpTransport.debug = true; before call, after String response = androidHttpTransport.responseDump; what is in response ?

Comment: or just use http://www.wsdl2code.com/, good tool)

Comment: Also make sure you have added `ksoap2` file to your `buildpath` and the package names are they right?

Comment: @Nomand I checked wsdl2code.com its good but its not a android coding. How will run a android coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ok I will send you all the classes and xml files. check and learn the web services concept.       


 LazyAdapter.java


        public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            java.net.URL urlImage;
            InputStream is ;
            private Activity activity;
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> twitterList;
            private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

            public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
                activity = a;
                twitterList=d;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return twitterList.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi=convertView;
                if(convertView==null)
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                TextView id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.playerId); // title
                TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.playerName); // artist name
                TextView country = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.countryName); // duration
                ImageView flag=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.countryFlag); // thumb image


                HashMap<String, String> valueList = new HashMap<String, String>();
                valueList = twitterList.get(position);


                // Setting all values in listview
                id.setText(valueList.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_ID));
                name.setText(valueList.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_NAME));
                country.setText(valueList.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_COUNTRYNAME));
                String countryFlag = valueList.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_COUNTRYFLAG);
                try {
                    urlImage = new java.net.URL(countryFlag);
                    is = (InputStream) urlImage.getContent();


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
                flag.setImageDrawable(d);
                return vi;
            }
        }


    SingleMenuItemActivity.java



    public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

        URL url;
        Bitmap bimage;
        java.net.URL urlImage;
        InputStream is ;
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_COUNTRYNAME = "countryName";
        private static final String TAG_COUNTRYFLAG = "countryFlag";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

            // getting intent data
            Intent in = getIntent();

            // Get JSON values from previous intent
            String playerId = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
            String playerName = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
            String countryName = in.getStringExtra(TAG_COUNTRYNAME);
            String countryFlag = in.getStringExtra(TAG_COUNTRYFLAG);



            // Displaying all values on the screen
            TextView lblId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerId);
            TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerName);
            TextView lblCountryName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countryName);
            ImageView lblCountryFlag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.countryFlag);
            try {
                urlImage = new java.net.URL(countryFlag);
                is = (InputStream) urlImage.getContent();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
            lblId.setText(playerId);
            lblName.setText(playerName);
            lblCountryName.setText(countryName);
            lblCountryFlag.setImageDrawable(d);

        }

    }


    main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Main ListView 
             Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
        -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>



    list_item.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/countryFlag"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/playerId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/playerName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:textColor="#acacac" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/countryName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#5d5d5d" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



    single_list_item.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:text="PlayerId :"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/playerId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#43bd00"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:text="PlayerName :"
                android:textColor="#acacac"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/playerName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:textColor="#acacac" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="CountryName :"
                android:textColor="#5d5d5d" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/countryName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#5d5d5d" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="CountryFlag :"
                android:textColor="#43bd00" >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/countryFlag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below example code for retrieving data from web services using SOAP.It will help you a lot. Let me know you have any doubts.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WSDemoFootBallActivity extends Activity  {

SoapObject resultinMethod;
TextView tvResult;
URL url;
Bitmap bimage;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
static final String TAG_ID = "id";
static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
static final String TAG_COUNTRYNAME = "countryName";
static final String TAG_COUNTRYFLAG = "countryFlag";

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "AllPlayerNames";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu";
private static final String URL = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL&quot";
//you can get these values from the wsdl file^

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("bSelected", true);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope sse=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
    sse.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    sse.dotNet=true;

    HttpTransportSE htse=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, sse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SoapObject res=(SoapObject) sse.bodyIn;

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> valuesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < res.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

        SoapObject  namesObject = (SoapObject) res.getProperty(i);
        for(int j=0;j<namesObject.getPropertyCount();j++)
        {
            Object objectNames=namesObject.getProperty(j);
            SoapObject soapObjectIds = (SoapObject)objectNames;
            SoapObject soapObjectNames=(SoapObject) objectNames;
            SoapObject soapObjectCountryNames = (SoapObject)objectNames;
            SoapObject soapObjectCountryFlag = (SoapObject)objectNames;

            String id = soapObjectIds.getProperty("iId").toString();
            String stringNames=soapObjectNames.getProperty("sName").toString();
            String countryName = soapObjectCountryNames.getProperty("sCountryName").toString();
            String countryFlag = soapObjectCountryFlag.getProperty("sCountryFlagLarge").toString();     


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, stringNames);
            map.put(TAG_COUNTRYNAME, countryName);
            map.put(TAG_COUNTRYFLAG, countryFlag);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            valuesList.add(map);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */


    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, valuesList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map = valuesList.get(position);
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID,map.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_ID));
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME,map.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_NAME));
            in.putExtra(TAG_COUNTRYNAME, map.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_COUNTRYNAME));
            in.putExtra(TAG_COUNTRYFLAG,map.get(WSDemoFootBallActivity.TAG_COUNTRYFLAG));
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please give me a LazyAdapter.java and SingleMenuItemActivity.java